# Sending email with large body is failing

Tags: html-email

When sending an email from C# with body being large is resulting in failure in sending email

```
Mailbox unavailable.
```

The email is working fine with a smaller body. I am using html body to true property..

Thanks,
Zafar

Code:

```
using (MailMessage _mailMsg = new MailMessage())
                    {
                        _mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailFrom"].ToString());
                        _mailMsg.Body = mail.Body;
                        _mailMsg.Subject = mail.Subject;
                        _mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        foreach (string strEmailIds in mailTo)
                        {
                            if (strEmailIds != null && strEmailIds != string.Empty && strEmailIds != "")
                            {
                                if (!_mailMsg.To.Contains(new MailAddress(strEmailIds)))
                                    _mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(strEmailIds));
                            }
                        }
                        //_mailMsg.CC.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailCC"].ToString());
                        using (SmtpClient _client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"].ToString()))
                        {

                            if (_mailMsg.To.Count > 0)
                            {

                                _client.Send(_mailMsg);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _mailMsg.Subject = "No emails associated with the portfolio: " + account + " Original Email:" + mail.Subject;
                                _mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailSuppotTeam"].ToString()));
                                _client.Send(_mailMsg);
                            }
```

Comment: please specify: what is large and which methods you use for sending email, feel free to post the actual code, that should give more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with sending email to cross domain email id and was resulting in the Generic exception
"Mailbox unavailable." May be this is one of the reason behind the above exception.

Answer (score 1):

Oke, on thing it could be is that the mail server rejects big messages. Let exclude that one... I assume you have a local smtp mail server installed (check for telnet 127.0.0.1 25 that should give a sort of reply) configure the mail server [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"]] for 127.0.0.1, can you send big mails now?

If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"] is already the local SMTP server then:
a) stop that smtp service (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) for a moment (via the command services.msc)
b) send a small email
c) go to c:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup and edit the message via notepad so that it becomes a BIG email
d) start the smtp service again (services.msc)